# Android app supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play

I try upload my app in play market but an error occurred - 0 supported devices. What is wrong in my manifest file? Maybe set use features flag on false?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23"
    android:maxSdkVersion="23" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="SeeLife"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.AuthorizationActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="SeeLife"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity"
        android:label="ServiceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.RegistrationActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.TodayActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_today"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.SubcategoriesActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_subcategories"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.CategoryDetailActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_category_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_video_player" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.FilmActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_film" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".project.activity.CommentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_comment" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Is that a TV app ? Maybe your app has `android.software.leanback` and the screen supported by the TV is not referenced in your <compatible-screens> tag

Answer (score 1):

I think is because you set the `android.software.leanback` feature as required.

Also, the RECORD_AUDIO features implies the presence of a microphone which is not supported by Android TV Apps

[Declaring permissions that imply hardware features](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#hardware-permissions)

Comment: in my app I use youtubeapi, this is not TV app

Comment: @DenisMakovsky so the best thing to do is to put `<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />` in your manifest

Comment: @DenisMakovsky any news?